# Does Discard in python indictate code is bad?

Tags: python, compilation, abstract-syntax-tree

if I try compile some bad python code:

```
bad_code = """
r
"""

import compiler
print compiler.parse(bad_code)
```

I get

```
Module(None, Stmt([Discard(Name('r'))]))
```

Can I always assume that if I see Discard in the tree, that the code is bad ? 
Or is it more subtle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Discard is generated for any expression that has its result unused:

```
>>> compiler.parse("1")
Module(None, Stmt([Discard(Const(1))]))

>>> compiler.parse("def x(): yield 1")
Module(None, Stmt([Function(None, 'x', (), (), 0, None, Stmt([Discard(Yield(Const(1)))]))]))
```

For example, `InteractiveCodeGenerator` emits a `PRINT_EXPR` for Discard nodes, while normal `CodeGenerator` just `POP_TOP`s its result away.

Your "bad code" is not bad syntax-wise. Bad code will get you a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: It will generate a NameError though, I was wondering if I could use the AST to find code that will cause problems like this ?

Comment: Nope, that is impossible to know until runtime. `globals()['a'] = 1; a`.